# Как можно каждые несколько секунд проверять соединение с устройством Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Мне нужно что бы каждые например 5 секунд проверять установлено ли соединение с устройством, если нет то выводить Toast что соединение утеряно, как можно такое сделать?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону Broadcast receiver

Comment: @danilshik спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
  registerReceiver(BluetoothCheck, filter1);
}
  private final BroadcastReceiver BluetoothCheck = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
           if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {

             //Код...

           }
    }
};
```